# AWS CloudWatch custom metrics not showing up after change in instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Actually, i've changed the instance type of ec2 instance and after some days, i've noticed that cloudwatch custom metrics for disk are not showing up in cloudwatch. I've observed that it was happened after change in instacne type from r4 to r5 of the ec2 instance and it is letting the device name change from **/dev/sda1** to **/dev/nvme0n1p1**. Also, in cloudwatch graphs, it is showing old device name only ie **/dev/sda1** and it is not getting any data due to the old device name. In that case, how can i send new devices's disk metrics to cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0):

From [Amazon EC2 Instance Types - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/):

> With R5d instances, local NVMe-based SSDs are physically connected to the host server and provide block-level storage that is coupled to the lifetime of the R5 instance

The NVMe disks are [instance store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) (temporary) disks. There are no metrics provided for Instance Store disks.

R4 family instances only use Amazon EBS disks, which have metrics available. You would have at least one Amazon EBS disk on the instance, which would be the boot disk.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it turned out that the instance-type was itself a factor in the metrics produced by Cloudwatch Agent; meaning that, while I thought I was simply looking at a graph of the `mem_used_percent` metric, in reality it was of `[t2.medium, mem_used_percent]`. So, adding the `[t2.large, mem_used_percent]` metric to the graph was all it took to be able to see both the before- and after.